# How to run pentaho pig job in java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, pentaho

I have created job in spoon where i am using pig script executor.in UI it works fine.it is calling pig script and giving desired output

> Output(s): Successfully stored 445454 records (15256953 bytes) in:
>   "/hive/warehouse/weblogs/aggregate_pig_test3"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 445454 Total bytes written :
>   15256953 Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags
>   proactively spilled: 0 Total records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_local270305097_0001 2016/04/06 17:24:12 - Pig Script
>   Executor - 2016/04/06 17:24:12 - Success! 2016/04/06 17:24:12 - Pig
>   Script Executor - Num successful jobs: 1 num failed jobs: 0

now when i use same .kjb file in java i dont get desired output.it seems like my script is not executed still i am not getting any exception

my java code

```
         KettleEnvironment.init();
         Properties props = new Properties();
        JobMeta  metadata = new JobMeta("pig.kjb",null);
        Job  job = new Job (null, metadata);
        job.start();
        job.waitUntilFinished();

        System.err.println(job.getStatus());
          if (job.getErrors()!=0) {
            System.out.println("Error encountered!");
         }

    } catch (KettleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output of java method:

> 2016/04/06 18:25:59 - pig - Start of job execution 2016/04/06 18:25:59
>   - pig - Starting entry [Pig Script Executor] 2016/04/06 18:25:59 - pig - Finished job entry [Pig Script Executor] (result= 2016/04/06 18:25:59 - pig - Job execution finished

But nothing happens.like above in spoon UI it stores file. I dont know what is missing. Why is my java code is not executing.

Comment: may be you need to add the full path of the pig.kjb...

Comment: yes i have tried with that...full path to pig.kjb..still no effect..

Answer (score 1):

I missed -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS which was required for hadoop configuration in pentaho.